# Map withDefault not wokring kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, dictionary, hashmap, mutablemap

I have a mutable map in which I want a default value 0 for key not found

I tried the below code `withDefault({somevalue})`but still returns `null`

```
val attributes = mutableMapOf<String, Int>().withDefault({0})
attributes["orange"]=345
println(attributes["orange"])
println(attributes["orang"])
```

The result I get is `345 null` instead of `345 0`

What is it I am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*withDefault* is to be used with *getValue* and not with *get* resp. *[...]*:

```
val attributes = mutableMapOf<String, Int>().withDefault { 0 }

val result = attributes["orang"]
println(result)   // Output: null

val result2 = attributes.getValue("orang")
println(result2)   // Output: 0
```

See: [withDefault](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/with-default.html)

> This implicit default value is used when the original map doesn't
> contain a value for the key specified and ***a value is obtained with
> Map.getValue function*** [...]